# How to check if a set of conditions in a string is true

Tags: c#, eval

I have a string that contains condition expressions:

```
"weight=65,age>18"
```

I want to check if the condition is true.

For example:

```
int weight = 70;
int age= 19;
string conditions = "weight=65,age>18";
```

In the above example `weight` condition is `false` and `age` condition is `true`. Hence the result should be `false`.

I want to check the condition and return if the condition is satisfied.

Comment: In other words, you want to write a parser to have a scripting language?

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, exactly

Comment: 1) Define the grammar of your condition expressions. 2) Write a parser which parses this grammar, probably into some sort of tree structure. 3) Write an interpreter which processes this parsed output, and checks whether your inputs match the conditions

Comment: I think this is just an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What was your original issue you were trying to solve with this approach. Why you have strings that cointain condition expressions at all?

Comment: @Tim Schmelter It is related to desiging flowchart gateways. The flowchart gateways has conditions,  which are stored in a database as a string.

Comment: @MustafaBazghandi: So why they are stored as string and not in a way that you can recover them easily?  Just spend more time in your datamodel and less in writing parsers.

Comment: Dear editors, please open the question . This question is clear and does not needs to be more focused. It is solved via DataTable Compute method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a *parser*, as a possible quick solution you can try `DataTable.Compute` one:

```
using System.Data;

...

private static T RunWithVariables<T>(
  string formula, params (string name, object value)[] variables) {
  
  using DataTable table = new();

  foreach (var (n, v) in variables)
    table.Columns.Add(n, v is null ? typeof(object) : v.GetType());

  table.Rows.Add();

  foreach (var (n, v) in variables)
    table.Rows[0][n] = v;

  table.Columns.Add("__Result", typeof(double)).Expression = formula 
    ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(formula)); ;

  return (T)(Convert.ChangeType(table.Compute($"Min(__Result)", null), typeof(T)));
}
```

Then

```
int weight = 70;
int age = 19;

string conditions = "weight=65,age>18";

var result = RunWithVariables<bool>(conditions.Replace(",", " and "), 
  (nameof(weight), weight), 
  (nameof(age), age));
```